# How should I configure a Solr query to search for a term in multiple fields?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm trying to construct a Solr query to search for the term "tree" in the fields "type" and "desc".

Here's my attempt so far:

```
?q=tree
&defType=dismax
&qf=type desc
```

However, this only works for exact matches.
It does not find "treehouse" or "big-tree".

How should I modify the search query?

Answer (score 0):

I you want your query should match with words "treehouse" "big-tree", then you have to apply correct string tokenizers on that fields accordingly ,

To match word treehouse may be you have to use DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory

To match big-tree , you can use [WordDelemeterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory)

Refer [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

Answer (score 0):

Terms component can be used in this case as well:

/terms?terms.fl=type&terms.fl=desc&terms.regex=tree.*

refer to -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component